# Build a navigation from a List to generate pages

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to make a wpf desktop application. I want to make a window which is split in two halfs. The left side should contain a list (like a navigation) and the right side a page. Everytime I click on an item in the list, I want to load a new page. The Page contains a `TreeView`. At the moment I have a class `TreeViewData` which contains the data for the TreeView. Those are stored in a `List`. And in my `Main` I do

```
foreach(var t in TreeViewDataList)
{
    TreeViewDataWindow w2 = new TreeViewDataWindow(t);
    w2.Show();
}
```

to show the TreeViews. But it is really user unfriendly to have 20 open windows. Can someone give me a tip how I can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having ViewModels and Views defined, so i'm proposing the solution, and instead of TreeView i'm using ListBox, 
in MainWindow,

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:AdvancedViewModel}">
                <view:AdvancedView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:RegularViewModel}">
                <view:RegularView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Here i've used some view and viewmodel for example purpose,

your views,
First View

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication5.RegularView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="Fom Regular"/>
</Grid>
```

Second view

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication5.AdvancedView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="From Advanced"/>
</Grid>
```

and you MainViewModel have to be like ,

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> viewModels;

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ViewModels
    {
        get { return viewModels; }
        set { viewModels = value; }
    }

    private ViewModelBase selectedViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { selectedViewModel = value; }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        ViewModels.Add(new RegularViewModel());
        ViewModels.Add(new AdvancedViewModel());
        SelectedViewModel = ViewModels[0];
    }

}

public class ViewModelBase
{
}
public class RegularViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

}
public class AdvancedViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast response. Okay you create a new usercontrol instead of a page. It is not what I was looking for but I will give it a try now.

Comment: this is one concept, you can try with the controls you wanted.

Comment: Now i did unterstand the concept! And its what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer :D. I was confused about the regular view and the advanced view. I finished my homework now. :)